# How To Remove both duplicates (original and duplicate) from text?

Tags: html, windows, notepad++

I need to remove both duplicates (2 or more repeated) like:

```
admin@admin.com
user@user.com
admin@admin.com
bla@bla.com
admin@admin.com
```

result:

```
user@user.com
bla@bla.com
```

There is a way to do it online, or offline?
Thank you.

Comment: I think this might be very hard to swing in Notepad++.  Are you limited to this tool, or do you have other options?

Comment: Is sorting the file an option?